# How to identify critical sections in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, critical-section

EDIT:This is not the same thing as the post "CRITICAL_SECTION in c#" as suggested by someone else. This post is about how to identify code that needs to be done in a critical section. The suggested duplicate post is asking about how to use the Windows OS API for critical sections. Not even close to the same.

Learning about multi-threading and async code. Struggling a bit with identifying critical sections. Not really sure what is shared and what is exclusive between context switches. Difference between how value types and reference types are handled. Whether a local variable vs. external variable vs. a parameter passed in is handled in a method.

Below is some code just specifically for this exercise. Assume there are multiple threads that can call into the method with different parameter values. I also added a couple variables external to the method too.

First lets see if some assumptions are correct. CS is "critical section" for convenience.

1. `++localX` needs to be in a CS since it is a local variable. `int localX = 0` is ok because this is atomic in C#. i.e. a thread won't set `localX` back to `0` for another thread when it initially declares the variable.
2. `++externalX` needs to be in a CS since it is a shared resource. And needs to be declared volatile or a thread might act on a cached value and end up with the wrong result.
3. `externalParms.Add( parms[0] );` needs to be in a CS since the `Add` method is not thread safe and it is a shared resource. Should also be declared volatile.
4. `myList[localX] = externalX;` needs to be in a CS since the indexer is not thread safe and it is a local variable.

**Questions**

1. What about the ADO.NET code?

   - `using (var command = new SqlCommand(spName, connection))` Do I need to worry about a thread putting its `spName` into another threads `command` object?
   - `command.Parameters.AddRange(parms);` I'm adding values to a collection. This is not threadsafe and needs to be in a CS?
   - `await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();` `command` is a local variable. Documentation doesn't say anything about the `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` method being threadsafe. CS or no CS?
2. `parms[0].Value = rnum;` needs to be in a CS?

Arbitrary code:

```
int externalX = 10;
List<SqlParameter> externalParms = new List<SqlParameter>();
internal async Task SampleExecuteNonQueryAsync(string spName, SqlParameter[] parms)
{
    int localX = 0;
    List<int> myList = new List<int>() { -1,-1};
    Random rnd = new Random();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(spName, connection))
        {
            ++localX;
            int rnum = rnd.Next(1, 100);
            parms[0].Value = rnum;

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddRange(parms);
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

            ++externalX;                    
        }
    }
    myList[localX] = externalX;
    externalParms.Add( parms[0] );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CRITICAL\_SECTION in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156349/critical-section-in-c-sharp)

Comment: No, that is not correct.  You must focus on any variables that one thread might read and another might write.  There is only one, externalParms.  If you properly await this method and *then* use externalParms then there is no risk at all.  Which is the only way to do it right, so no problems at all.

Comment: This question is the textbook definition of "too broad". There's about 7 or 8 separate questions here.

Comment: @ adityap - My post is about identifying critical sections, the post you mention is about using the Windows OS API. Totally different. @spender - I can see why you would say that. But really I just want to know how to identify a critical section. I used lots of examples since people often give quick vague answers and didn't want to miss anything.

Comment: I realise/hope that the code example is just that, an example, as some of the things you are doing are really unusual.  This kind of threading problem (keeping track of values and putting them in the same list in different threads) is 'advanced' and is rarely required in general day-to-day programming.  If I was running a project with this code in it, I would probably reject it, as these issues could be removed entirely with a decent design.

Comment: Yes, it is just code slapped together to hit all points I could think of based on tutorials, posts, and documentation I've read. Not code in a real project. Hence the line "Arbitrary Code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused and overthinking things.

Any 'stack' based variable (i.e. local variables) are 'per-thread', so there is no need to lock anything for them, each thread will have an entirely separate one.

If you are concerned that more than 1 thread will access `externalParms` then use one of the collections made for this purpose: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/

Comment: I think this makes sense now. To be clear though based on this post, I would also need to lock the "++externalX;" https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1030252/Multithreading-in-Csharp-NET-Part

Comment: Also based on this quote "ADO.NET is optimized for performance, throughput, and scalability. As a result, the ADO.NET objects do not lock resources and must only be used on a single thread" from this url https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx. My sample code would be ok, since the ADO.NET objects are created locally on each thread. If I had created the objects say at the class level and tried to access them from multiple threads it would be a problem.

Comment: If you 'just' want to increment a variable in a thread-safe manner, use `Interlocked.Increment` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netframework-4.7.2  .

Comment: Thanx for the help. I think 1 of the first tutorials I read was wrong about local variables and multi-threading and that made everything confusing from there. Couldn't find something to state how memory is handled between context switches. etc.